# Drawing centered QCircuit diagram in two-column Revtex 4-1 article

Tags: revtex, qcircuit

I'm having trouble centering a qcircuit diagram in latex. I'm using revtex4-1.

I have tried the using `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}` but instead of rendering the diagram in the center of the document rather than in one of the columns, it simply doesn't draw at all despite the lack of errors thrown.

Here is the diagram in-progress. It is too wide at present and clips into the other column of text in the actual document.

The diagram in progress should look like this: [image: expected result]

Instead, my compiled document just has a blank space where the diagram would appear if confined to a single column:
[image]

```
\documentclass[%
reprint,
nofootinbib,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\input{Qcircuit}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centerline{                                                                  
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em @!R{                                             
\lstick{\ket{j_1}} & \gate{H} & \gate{R_2} & \qw & \dots & & \qw & \gate{R_n}\    & \qw & \qw \\
\lstick{\ket{j_2}} & \qw & \ctrl{-1} & \qw & \dots & & \qw & \qw & \gate{H} &     \qw & \dots & & \qw & \gate{R_{n-1}} & \qw & \qw\\ 
}}                                                                            
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Pasted below is Qcircuit.tex

```
\ProvidesPackage{qcircuit}[2014/06/29]
\RequirePackage{xy}

\DeclareOption{braket}{
    \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle{#1}\right\vert}}
    \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\vert{#1}\right\rangle}}
    }

\DeclareOption{qm}{
    \newcommand{\ip}[2]{\ensuremath{\left\langle{#1}\right\vert{#2}\rangle}}
    \newcommand{\melem}[3]{\ensuremath{\left\langle{#1}\right\vert{#2}\vert{#3}\rangle}}
    \newcommand{\expval}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}}
    \newcommand{\op}[2]{\ensuremath{\vert{#1}\rangle\langle{#2}\vert}}
    }

\ProcessOptions\relax

\xyoption{matrix}
\xyoption{frame}
\xyoption{arrow}
\xyoption{arc}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\else
\PackageWarningNoLine{Qcircuit}{Qcircuit is loading in Postscript mode.  The Xy-pic options ps and dvips will be loaded.  If you wish to use other Postscript drivers for Xy-pic, you must modify the code in Qcircuit.tex}
%    The following options load the drivers most commonly required to
%    get proper Postscript output from Xy-pic.  Should these fail to work,
%    try replacing the following two lines with some of the other options
%    given in the Xy-pic reference manual.
\xyoption{ps}
\xyoption{dvips}
\fi

% The following resets Xy-pic matrix alignment to the pre-3.8 default, as
% required by Qcircuit.
\entrymodifiers={!C\entrybox}

\newcommand{\qw}[1][-1]{\ar @{-} [0,#1]}
    % Defines a wire that connects horizontally.  By default it connects to the object on the left of the current object.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\qwx}[1][-1]{\ar @{-} [#1,0]}
    % Defines a wire that connects vertically.  By default it connects to the object above the current object.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\qwa}[1][-1]{\ar @{<-} [0,#1]}
    % Defines a wire that connects horizontally with an arrow.  By default it makes an end wire with an arrow indicating the end of the circuit.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\cw}[1][-1]{\ar @{=} [0,#1]}
    % Defines a classical wire that connects horizontally.  By default it connects to the object on the left of the current object.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\cwx}[1][-1]{\ar @{=} [#1,0]}
    % Defines a classical wire that connects vertically.  By default it connects to the object above the current object.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\cwa}[1][-1]{\ar @{<=} [0,#1]}
    % Defines a classical wire that connects horizontally with an arrow.  By default it makes an end wire with an arrow indicating the end of the circuit.
    % WARNING: Wire commands must appear after the gate in any given entry.
\newcommand{\cds}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \POS [0,0].[#1,0]="e",!C *{#2};"e"+ R \qw}
    % Allows the insertion of text without a box and exands circuit around this text.
    % This is useful for such things as ... to indicate a generalized circuit.
\newcommand{\gate}[1]{*+<.6em>{#1} \POS ="i","i"+UR;"i"+UL **\dir{-};"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+DR **\dir{-};"i"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qw}
    % Boxes the argument, making a gate.
\newcommand{\sgate}[2]{\gate{#1}  \qwx[#2]}
    % Creates a gate and a qwx wire going #2 spots below, for a gate split over
    % non-adjacent rows
\newcommand{\meter}{*=<1.8em,1.4em>{\xy ="j","j"-<.778em,.322em>;{"j"+<.778em,-.322em> \ellipse ur,_{}},"j"-<0em,.4em>;p+<.5em,.9em> **\dir{-},"j"+<2.2em,2.2em>*{},"j"-<2.2em,2.2em>*{} \endxy} \POS ="i","i"+UR;"i"+UL **\dir{-};"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+DR **\dir{-};"i"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qw}
    % Inserts a measurement meter.
    % In case you're wondering, the constants .778em and .322em specify
    % one quarter of a circle with radius 1.1em.
    % The points added at + and - <2.2em,2.2em> are there to strech the
    % canvas, ensuring that the size is unaffected by erratic spacing issues
    % with the arc.
\newcommand{\metersymb}{\xy ="j","j"-<.778em,.322em>;{"j"+<.778em,-.322em> \ellipse ur,_{}},"j"-<0em,.4em>;p+<.5em,.9em> **\dir{-},"j"+<2.2em,2.2em>*{},"j"-<2.2em,2.2em>*{} \endxy}
    % A longer meter
\newcommand{\meterB}[1]{*=<1.8em,2.6em>{\xy 0;<0em,-.8em>:
0*{\begingroup
\everymath{\scriptstyle}
\tiny #1 \endgroup},<0em,.7em>*{\xy ="j","j"-<.778em,-.322em>;{"j"+<.778em,.322em> \ellipse ur,_{}},"j"-<0em,-.2em>;p+<.5em,.9em> **\dir{-},"j"+<2.2em,2.2em>*{},"j"-<2.2em,2.2em>*{} \endxy} 
\endxy} \POS ="i","i"+UR;"i"+UL **\dir{-};"i"+DL **\dir{-};"i"+DR **\dir{-};"i"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qw}
    % A meter that allows for a measurement operator to be added below
\newcommand{\smeterB}[2]{\meterB{#1} \qwx[#2] \qw}
    % A split meter that allows for a measurement operator to be split over non-
    % adjacent rows
\newcommand{\measure}[1]{*+[F-:<.9em>]{#1} \qw}
    % Inserts a measurement bubble with user defined text.
\newcommand{\measuretab}[1]{*{\xy*+<.6em>{#1}="e";"e"+UL;"e"+UR **\dir{-};"e"+DR **\dir{-};"e"+DL **\dir{-};"e"+LC-<.5em,0em> **\dir{-};"e"+UL **\dir{-} \endxy} \qw}
    % Inserts a measurement tab with user defined text.
\newcommand{\measureD}[1]{*{\xy*+=<0em,.1em>{#1}="e";"e"+UR+<0em,.25em>;"e"+UL+<-.5em,.25em> **\dir{-};"e"+DL+<-.5em,-.25em> **\dir{-};"e"+DR+<0em,-.25em> **\dir{-};{"e"+UR+<0em,.25em>\ellipse^{}};"e"+C:,+(0,1)*{} \endxy} \qw}
    % Inserts a D-shaped measurement gate with user defined text.
\newcommand{\multimeasure}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \qw \POS[0,0].[#1,0];p !C *{#2},p \drop\frm<.9em>{-}}
    % Draws a multiple qubit measurement bubble starting at the current position and spanning #1 additional gates below.
    % #2 gives the label for the gate.
    % You must use an argument of the same width as #2 in \ghost for the wires to connect properly on the lower lines.
\newcommand{\multimeasureD}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \POS [0,0]="i",[0,0].[#1,0]="e",!C *{#2},"e"+UR-<.8em,0em>;"e"+UL **\dir{-};"e"+DL **\dir{-};"e"+DR+<-.8em,0em> **\dir{-};{"e"+DR+<0em,.8em>\ellipse^{}};"e"+UR+<0em,-.8em> **\dir{-};{"e"+UR-<.8em,0em>\ellipse^{}},"i" \qw}
    % Draws a multiple qubit D-shaped measurement gate starting at the current position and spanning #1 additional gates below.
    % #2 gives the label for the gate.
    % You must use an argument of the same width as #2 in \ghost for the wires to connect properly on the lower lines.
\newcommand{\control}{*!<0em,.025em>-=-<.2em>{\bullet}}
    % Inserts an unconnected control.
\newcommand{\controlo}{*+<.01em>{\xy -<.095em>*\xycircle<.19em>{} \endxy}}
    % Inserts a unconnected control-on-0.
\newcommand{\ctrl}[1]{\control \qwx[#1] \qw}
    % Inserts a control and connects it to the object #1 wires below.
\newcommand{\ctrlo}[1]{\controlo \qwx[#1] \qw}
    % Inserts a control-on-0 and connects it to the object #1 wires below.
\newcommand{\cctrl}[1]{\control \cwx[#1] \cw}
    % Inserts a classical control and connects it to the object #1 wires below. 
\newcommand{\cctrlo}[1]{\controlo \cwx[#1] \cw}
    % Inserts a classical control-on-0 and connects it to the object #1 wires below.    
\newcommand{\targ}{*+<.02em,.02em>{\xy ="i","i"-<.39em,0em>;"i"+<.39em,0em> **\dir{-}, "i"-<0em,.39em>;"i"+<0em,.39em> **\dir{-},"i"*\xycircle<.4em>{} \endxy} \qw}
    % Inserts a CNOT target.
\newcommand{\qswap}{*=<0em>{\times} \qw}
    % Inserts half a swap gate.
    % Must be connected to the other swap with \qwx.
\newcommand{\multigate}[2]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#2}} \POS [0,0]="i",[0,0].[#1,0]="e",!C *{#2},"e"+UR;"e"+UL **\dir{-};"e"+DL **\dir{-};"e"+DR **\dir{-};"e"+UR **\dir{-},"i" \qw}
    % Draws a multiple qubit gate starting at the current position and spanning #1 additional gates below.
    % #2 gives the label for the gate.
    % You must use an argument of the same width as #2 in \ghost for the wires to connect properly on the lower lines.
\newcommand{\ghost}[1]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#1}} \qw}
    % Leaves space for \multigate on wires other than the one on which \multigate appears.  Without this command wires will cross your gate.
    % #1 should match the second argument in the corresponding \multigate.
\newcommand{\push}[1]{*{#1}}
    % Inserts #1, overriding the default that causes entries to have zero size.  This command takes the place of a gate.
    % Like a gate, it must precede any wire commands.
    % \push is useful for forcing columns apart.
    % NOTE: It might be useful to know that a gate is about 1.3 times the height of its contents.  I.e. \gate{M} is 1.3em tall.
    % WARNING: \push must appear before any wire commands and may not appear in an entry with a gate or label.
\newcommand{\gategroup}[6]{\POS"#1,#2"."#3,#2"."#1,#4"."#3,#4"!C*+<#5>\frm{#6}}
    % Constructs a box or bracket enclosing the square block spanning rows #1-#3 and columns=#2-#4.
    % The block is given a margin #5/2, so #5 should be a valid length.
    % #6 can take the following arguments -- or . or _\} or ^\} or \{ or \} or _) or ^) or ( or ) where the first two options yield dashed and
    % dotted boxes respectively, and the last eight options yield bottom, top, left, and right braces of the curly or normal variety.  See the Xy-pic reference manual for more options.
    % \gategroup can appear at the end of any gate entry, but it's good form to pick either the last entry or one of the corner gates.
    % BUG: \gategroup uses the four corner gates to determine the size of the bounding box.  Other gates may stick out of that box.  See \prop.
\newcommand{\inputgroupv}[5]{\POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1"!C*+<#3>\frm{\{}, \POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1"*!C!<1.7em,#4>=<0em>{#5}}
    % Constructs an input group with label #5 and a grouping { from rows #1 to #2 with #3 and #4 controlling the spacing
\newcommand{\inputgroup}[4]{\POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1", \POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1"*!C!<1em,#3>=<0em>{#4}}
    % Constructs an input group with label #4 from rows #1 to #2 with #3 controlling the spacing
\newcommand{\inputgrouph}[5]{\POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1", \POS"#1,1"."#2,1"."#1,1"."#2,1"*!C!<#5,#3>=<0em>{#4}}
    % Constructs an input group with label #4 and a grouping /vdots from rows #1 to #2 with #3 and #5 controlling the spacing
\newcommand{\rstick}[1]{*!L!<-.5em,0em>=<0em>{#1}}
    % Centers the left side of #1 in the cell.  Intended for lining up wire labels.  Note that non-gates have default size zero.
\newcommand{\lstick}[1]{*!R!<.5em,0em>=<0em>{#1}}
    % Centers the right side of #1 in the cell.  Intended for lining up wire labels.  Note that non-gates have default size zero.
\newcommand{\ustick}[1]{*!D!<0em,-.5em>=<0em>{#1}}
    % Centers the bottom of #1 in the cell.  Intended for lining up wire labels.  Note that non-gates have default size zero.
\newcommand{\dstick}[1]{*!U!<0em,.5em>=<0em>{#1}}
    % Centers the top of #1 in the cell.  Intended for lining up wire labels.  Note that non-gates have default size zero.
\newcommand{\Qcircuit}{\xymatrix @*=<0em>}
    % Defines \Qcircuit as an \xymatrix with entries of default size 0em.
\newcommand{\link}[2]{\ar @{-} [#1,#2]}
    % Draws a wire or connecting line to the element #1 rows down and #2 columns forward.
\newcommand{\pureghost}[1]{*+<1em,.9em>{\hphantom{#1}}}
    % Same as \ghost except it omits the wire leading to the left. 

\endinput
```

Edit:

I am using (I think) `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95318/discussion-between-swickrotation-and-kurt).

Comment: A figure* will never appear on the same page as it is created.  Also, you need to make sure document class options like [aps] don't invoke endfloat.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have working copy of TeX handy, but the following code should allow you circuit to be typeset to a separate image file, which can then be included in your document in the standard way.  (The spacing parameters may need to be adjusted for your circuit.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\input{Qcircuit}% using  qcircuit version 2
\begin{document}
\hspace{1em}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\vspace{-.6em}\\
  \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em @!R{                                             
    \lstick{\ket{j_1}} & \gate{H} & \gate{R_2} & \qw & \dots & & \qw & \gate{R_n}\    & \qw & \qw \\
    \lstick{\ket{j_2}} & \qw & \ctrl{-1} & \qw & \dots & & \qw & \qw & \gate{H} &     \qw & \dots & & \qw & \gate{R_{n-1}} & \qw & \qw\\ 
  }
\vspace{.2em}\hspace{1.2em}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This does not really answer your question, but if the issue is some conflict between Qcircuit and the remainder of your document then it should avoid the problem.

In general, I'd recommend compiling your images separately anyhow.